# Using a Temporary Table in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, devexpress, temp-tables

I am trying to create and then call on a temp table in a stored procedure. What I am trying to accomplish is combining yearly data with quarterly data. For example: I have a field that has data for 2013. To get the yearly data I grouped by year, to get the quarterly data, I grouped by quarter. I would normally use a view for the yearly and call that view in the quarterly stored procedure. The reason I am trying to do this is because we cannot use views per the developers. So to get around this, I made a temp table with the yearly data.(see code below) When I execute this, it works fine, but when I try to add the stored procedure to Devexpress, it does not contain any fields. This is my first attempt at a temp table so if there are any errors or better ways to write this, please let me know. Thank you for your help.

```
CREATE TABLE #StdEcoYearlyData1(
  CaseCaseId int , 
  EcoYear int, 
  NetInvY  float, 
  NDCashY  float, 
  DiscCashY  float, 
  GrossGasY  float, 
  GrossOilY  float, 
  NetProdTaxY  float, 
  NetOpCostY  float,
  WellCostY  float, 
  NetOilY  float, 
  CoNetRevOilY  float, 
  CoNetRevGasY  float, 
  NetGasY  float, 
  NetLocalTaxY  float, 
  NetFixedCostY  float, 
  NetOtherCostY  float, 
  NetProfitY  float, 
  NetTransCostY  float
)

INSERT INTO #StdEcoYearlyData1 (
  CaseCaseId   , 
  EcoYear  , 
  NetInvY  , 
  NDCashY  , 
  DiscCashY  , 
  GrossGasY  , 
  GrossOilY  , 
  NetProdTaxY  , 
  NetOpCostY  ,
  WellCostY  , 
  NetOilY  , 
  CoNetRevOilY  , 
  CoNetRevGasY  , 
  NetGasY  , 
  NetLocalTaxY  , 
  NetFixedCostY  , 
  NetOtherCostY  , 
  NetProfitY  , 
  NetTransCostY  )
SELECT  rcl.CaseCaseId AS CaseId,  YEAR(rce.ecodate) as EYear,
  SUM(rce.NetInv) AS NetInvY, SUM(rce.NDCash) AS NDCashY, 
  SUM(rce.DiscCash) AS DiscCashY, SUM(rce.GrossGas) AS GrossGasY, 
  SUM(rce.GrossOil) AS GrossOilY, SUM(rce.NetProdTax) AS NetProdTaxY, 
  SUM(rce.NetOpCost) AS NetOpCostY, SUM(rce.WellCost) AS WellCostY, 
  SUM(rce.NetOil) AS NetOilY, SUM(rce.CoNetRevOil) AS CoNetRevOilY, 
  SUM(rce.CoNetRevGas) AS CoNetRevGasY, SUM(rce.NetGas) AS NetGasY, 
  Sum(rce.NetLocalTax) as NetLocalTaxY, Sum(rce.NetFixedCost) as NetFixedCostY, 
  Sum(rce.NetOtherCost) as NetOtherCostY, Sum(rce.NetProfit) as NetProfitY, 
  Sum(rce.NetTransCost) as NetTransCostY
from PhdRpt.RptCaseEco rce
   INNER JOIN PhdRpt.ReportCaseList rcl ON 
     rce.ReportRunCaseId = rcl.ReportRunCaseId
 group by rce.reportruncaseid,rcl.CaseCaseId,year(rce.EcoDate)


 select 
  rcl.CaseCaseId AS CaseId, 
  EcoYear  , 
  DATEPART(qq,rce.EcoDate) as Quarter,
  NetInvY  , 
  NDCashY  , 
  DiscCashY  , 
  GrossGasY  , 
  GrossOilY  , 
  NetProdTaxY  , 
  NetOpCostY  ,
  WellCostY  , 
  NetOilY  , 
  CoNetRevOilY  , 
  CoNetRevGasY  , 
  NetGasY  , 
  NetLocalTaxY  , 
  NetFixedCostY  , 
  NetOtherCostY  , 
  NetProfitY  , 
  NetTransCostY,  YEAR(rce.EcoDate) AS EcoYear, 
  SUM(rce.NetInv) AS NetInvSum, SUM(rce.NDCash) AS NDCashSum, 
  SUM(rce.DiscCash) AS DiscCashSum, SUM(rce.GrossGas) AS GrossGasSum, 
  SUM(rce.GrossOil) AS GrossOilSum, SUM(rce.NetProdTax) AS NetProdTaxSum, 
  SUM(rce.NetOpCost) AS NetOpCostSum, SUM(rce.WellCost) AS WellCostSum, 
  SUM(rce.NetOil) AS NetOilSum, SUM(rce.CoNetRevOil) AS CoNetRevOilSum, 
  SUM(rce.CoNetRevGas) AS CoNetRevGasSum, SUM(rce.NetGas) AS NetGasSum, 
  Sum(rce.NetLocalTax) as NetLocalTaxSum, Sum(rce.NetFixedCost) as NetFixedCostSum, 
  Sum(rce.NetOtherCost) as NetOtherCostSum, Sum(rce.NetProfit) as NetProfitSum, 
  Sum(rce.NetTransCost) as NetTransCostSum
 from PhdRpt.RptCaseEco rce
   INNER JOIN PhdRpt.ReportCaseList rcl ON 
     rce.ReportRunCaseId = rcl.ReportRunCaseId 
   INNER JOIN #StdEcoYearlyData1 sey on
    rce.ReportRunCaseId =  sey.CaseCaseId and 
    year(rce.ecodate) = sey.EcoYear
  group by 
  EcoYear  , 
  NetInvY  , 
  NDCashY  , 
  DiscCashY  , 
  GrossGasY  , 
  GrossOilY  , 
  NetProdTaxY  , 
  NetOpCostY  ,
  WellCostY  , 
  NetOilY  , 
  CoNetRevOilY  , 
  CoNetRevGasY  , 
  NetGasY  , 
  NetLocalTaxY  , 
  NetFixedCostY  , 
  NetOtherCostY  , 
  NetProfitY,
  NetTransCostY, 
  rcl.CaseCaseId,
  YEAR(rce.EcoDate),
  DATEPART(qq,rce.EcoDate)

  order by rcl.CaseCaseId


drop table #StdEcoYearlyData1
```

[image: This is the result of the code]

Comment: Instead of creating the temp table and then inserting, you could just do `SELECT ... INTO #StdEcoYearlyData1 ...` in your query to select and insert at the same time.

Comment: This, "when I try to add the stored procedure to Devexpress, it does not contain any fields." is not clear.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk I add the stored procedure to the DataSet and it does not contain any fields.

Comment: Added the stored procedure to the what?  Have you attempted to execute this stored procedure?

Comment: It executes just fine but it does not populate any data when it is added to the DataSet in Devexpress.

Comment: I am wondering if there is something in the code that is not allowing the data to populate in Devexpress (report designer)